# How to solve the non-negative subset sum using recursion in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

I am really confused by a question that says:

> Given a set of non-negative integers, and a value `sum`, the goal is to identify all subsets whose sum of elements is equal to `sum`. For example, if the set of non-negative integers is `{3; 34; 4; 12; 5; 2}` and `sum = 9`, then answer is `{4; 5}` and `{4; 2; 3}`.

This question must be solved through a recursive method (one recursion function and one main `string[]args` function) but I have no idea on how to make it. Can someone give a hint?

Comment: Confusion can help sometimes. What has been your approach and efforts till now to come up with solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you asked for a hint rather than code, I'll give you a pointer on algorithm to get you started.

Generally recursive algorithms look something like:

```
recursiveFunction(currentResult, context)
    if currentResult satisfies given condition
        process currentResult
    for each possibleResult in context
        recursiveFunction(possibleResult, contextWithResultRemoved)
```

In your case the signature of the method will be something like:

```
public void allSubsetsWithSum(int targetSum, Set<Integer> current, Set<Integer> remaining)
```

The satisfying condition test just compares the sum of current to the target.

The 'for each' would just look at each integer in `remaining` and move it to `current` before recursing.

There are efficiency shortcuts such as not processing integers from `remaining` that will make the sum exceed your target. But that isn't necessary to make the algorithm to work.

Hopefully that will get you started. Ask further questions if you don't understand the hints.